# How to swap keyboard chars in haskell

Tags: haskell, io, keyboard

I want to change the charaters keys shown on the input of the I/O operation.
For example, let's say the key `'b'` is swapped to `'a'`, 
  then I want this result:
  if I type the key **b**, I will get **a**

```
Prelude> getChar
a   -- I actually typed the key b
'a'
```

Thank you!

Comment: You will get better answers if you give more context--what is your ultimate objective?

Comment: well, unfortunately, I think it's just pointless

Answer (score 3):

You can't modify `getChar`. However, you can do something like this:

```hs
Prelude> let swap :: Char -> Char; swap 'b' = 'a'; swap c = c
Prelude> fmap swap getChar
b'a'
```

If you want to delete the character `b` and replace it with the character `a` then you could do:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let getChar' :: IO Char;
Prelude|     getChar' = do
Prelude|         c <- getChar
Prelude|         if c == 'b'
Prelude|             then do
Prelude|                 putChar '\b' -- delete the previous character
Prelude|                 putChar 'a'  -- write a new character
Prelude|                 return 'a'
Prelude|             else return c
Prelude| :}
Prelude> getChar'
a'a'              -- I typed in `a'
Prelude> getChar'
a'a'              -- I typed in `b'
Prelude> getChar'
c'c'              -- I typed in `c'
```

More succinctly:

```
Prelude> let replace c = putChar '\b' >> putChar c >> return c
Prelude> let swap 'b' = replace 'a'; swap c = return c
Prelude> getChar >>= swap
a'a'                      -- I typed in `a'
Prelude> getChar >>= swap
a'a'                      -- I typed in `b'
Prelude> getChar >>= swap
c'c'                      -- I typed in `c'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a little different, I actually reupdated the question to clarify it, but thank you

Comment: The first version could also be written as `fmap swap getChar`